# Copying files in bash

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Im learning bash and I have a question about how to copy files from fatherly folder into another folder when user types "0". (for example from K2 to K1) And I don't know how to do so.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 $2 $3 $4
K1=$1
K2=$2
if [ $4 -eq "0" ] then
cp -v ../$2/*.{png,bmp,jpg,xcf,pcx} .
cp -v ../$2/*.{png,bmp,jpg,xcf,pcx} ./$1
fi
```

that's all I wrote, could you help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Type your number: "
read ANSWER
if [ "$ANSWER" == "0" ] ; then
    # Put here your cp commands
fi
```

Comment: Numeric comparison, not textual?

Comment: `[` uses just one `=` for comparison.

Comment: ... with `==` it will work in bash, but not in general shell. And there is no reason why this shouldn't work in any POSIX shell.

Comment: Always use `=` in `[...]`. If you rely on `==` working, you may as well rely on `[[...]]` working as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works! However, it works only when I write specific folders name in my cp commands,and I need to use arguments for that... First arguments would be the name of the first folder, and the second one would be the name of a fatherly folder. 
SOrry if these question may seem idiotic, but I'm green at this... Learning!